# Quick tweaks to make a boring standalone web form look nicer?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple one-page calculator, heavy with JavaScript and form elements. Here is a static snapshot of the page as an example: http://pastehtml.com/view/1ce4ppo.html

Obviously it's very plain and I haven't put much emphasis on the layout of it yet. But this prototype is about to be shown to the client in a few hours. There is the understanding that it is a mockup prototype, so the client is not expecting anything design-wise, but I wouldn't mind if it looked a bit nicer.

What are some quick and easy tweaks I can make so that the page looks a little better? I'm terrible with colors and design but I know CSS quite well (like an English major who knows correct spelling and grammar but is terrible at writing a story).

Also, I am using jQuery in the form, so anything involving jQuery is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the [Blueprint CSS template](http://www.blueprintcss.org) You can use just the form CSS, [seen here](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/forms.html). All you have to do is add some classes to the HTML and you've got some decent forms.

Answer (score 1):

give this a quick read: http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/
i dont know if the javascript load is worth it for what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I really like narrative style forms, where form elements are integrated in sentences which guide the user through the form-filling. Might not be for everybody(every form) but I think it's a really nice way of making your forms user friendly and stand out from the rest. Here you can find an example: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1007

When it comes to styling select, radio or checkbox inputs I prefer http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/.

Comment: I wish I could remember what the source was (IIRC it was reputable), but I read recently that the madlib style forms actually hindered form completion.   Fwiw, I do like them, but I (and most people here) are above the average user in terms of computer-knowledge, so just because I find them easy doesnt mean others do.

Comment: Ok, form-completion might be a showstopper for some forms, but I think for a simple sign-up form (where no real data is required) or a form that asks for things that are not your name, email and stuff (like the example of the questioner) it could help the user filling the form more easy. Sure, you can't tell if they'll like it, but at least you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one of the free template sites out there.  I use them all the time, especially for a mock-up since I'm also not a design person.  And in a lot of cases the customer enjoys the look or doesn't care.  Just check what the requirements are for using the template, if there are any.